# Rotating multi-dimensional array by 90 degrees clockwise

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, rotation, transpose

I've been able to work out the bulk of the problem. But my output keeps throwing an exception. I'm sure it's something minor, but I can't seem to figure out how to make this work right. I'm including the exception, the task as originally worded to me, along with my code so far:

Using formula `array[j][n - 1 - i]` I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 4
> at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:20)

If I use `array[j][n - i]` I get no exception, but it isn't the correct output order.

Been stuck on this for a week!

> Given a rectangle array `n×m` in size. Rotate it by 90 degrees clockwise, by recording the result into the new array m×n in size.
>
> Input data format:
>
> Input the two numbers `n` and `m`, not exceeding 100, and then an array `n×m` in size.
>
> Output data format:
>
> Output the resulting array. Separate numbers by a single space in the output.
>
> Sample Input 1:
>
> ```
> 3 4
>
> 11 12 13 14
> 21 22 23 24
> 31 32 33 34
> ```
>
> Sample Output 1:
>
> ```
> 31 21 11
> 32 22 12
> 33 23 13
> 34 24 14
> ```

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int m = scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] array = new int[n][m];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                array[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[j][n - 1 - i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only rotating it 90 degrees, you're just starting from the end of the row to the beginning while moving columns left and right. So your code should just be:

```java
int n = 3;
int m = 4;

int[][] array = {
        {11, 12, 13, 14},
        {21, 22, 23, 24},
        {31, 32, 33, 34}};

for (int col = 0; col < m; col++) {
    for (int row = n - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
        System.out.print(array[row][col] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```